# How to find the repeater item where the event was triggered?

Tags: asp.net, events, drop-down-menu, repeater

My repeater structure is like this

```
---------------------------------
| Repeater                      |
---------------------------------
| Dropdownlist    |   Label     |
---------------------------------
```

Every repeater item has a dropdownlist and a label. Based on the value selected in the dropdownlist, I would like to call a method in code behind to compute a value and set it in label.
But i'm facing a problem with the traditional SelectedIndexChanged event. It doesnt tell me the parent or repeater item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cast the sender of the selectedindexchaged event to a control.

find tis parent...do this until u get an object that is a repeater item...